# Отправка Socket

Tags: java, android

Есть 2 приложения, клиент и сервер. Клиент отправляет сообщение серверу по локальному адресу при помощи сокетов. Все доходит. Я подключаю 2 телефона к одному vpn серверу. Сервер выдает устройствам "свои" локальные адреса. Пытаюсь отправить сообщение с одного телефона на другой при помощи новых адресов, выданных впн сервером, ничего не происходит. Что я делаю не правильно?

КОД КЛИЕНТА

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 TextView textResponse;
 EditText editTextAddress, editTextPort;
 Button buttonConnect, buttonClear;

 EditText welcomeMsg;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  editTextAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);
  editTextPort = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.port);
  buttonConnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect);
  buttonClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clear);
  textResponse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.response);

  welcomeMsg = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.welcomemsg);

  buttonConnect.setOnClickListener(buttonConnectOnClickListener);

  buttonClear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    textResponse.setText("");
   }
  });
 }

 OnClickListener buttonConnectOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View arg0) {

   String tMsg = welcomeMsg.getText().toString();
   if(tMsg.equals("")){
    tMsg = null;
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Welcome Msg sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }

   MyClientTask myClientTask = new MyClientTask(editTextAddress
     .getText().toString(), Integer.parseInt(editTextPort
     .getText().toString()),
     tMsg);
   myClientTask.execute();
  }
 };

 public class MyClientTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

  String dstAddress;
  int dstPort;
  String response = "";
  String msgToServer;

  MyClientTask(String addr, int port, String msgTo) {
   dstAddress = addr;
   dstPort = port;
   msgToServer = msgTo;
  }

  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

   Socket socket = null;
   DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
   DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;

   try {
    socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);
    dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(
      socket.getOutputStream());
    dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

    if(msgToServer != null){
     dataOutputStream.writeUTF(msgToServer);
    }

    response = dataInputStream.readUTF();

   } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    response = "IOException: " + e.toString();
   } finally {
    if (socket != null) {
     try {
      socket.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }

    if (dataOutputStream != null) {
     try {
      dataOutputStream.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }

    if (dataInputStream != null) {
     try {
      dataInputStream.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }
   }
   return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
   textResponse.setText(response);
   super.onPostExecute(result);
  }

 }

}
```

КОД СЕРВЕРА

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 TextView info, infoip, msg;
 String message = "";
 ServerSocket serverSocket;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
  infoip = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoip);
  msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msg);

  infoip.setText(getIpAddress());

  Thread socketServerThread = new Thread(new SocketServerThread());
  socketServerThread.start();
 }

 @Override
 protected void onDestroy() {
  super.onDestroy();

  if (serverSocket != null) {
   try {
    serverSocket.close();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
 }

 private class SocketServerThread extends Thread {

  static final int SocketServerPORT = 8080;
  int count = 0;

  @Override
  public void run() {
   Socket socket = null;
   DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
   DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;

   try {
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SocketServerPORT);
    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

     @Override
     public void run() {
      info.setText("I'm waiting here: "
        + serverSocket.getLocalPort());
     }
    });

    while (true) {
     socket = serverSocket.accept();
     dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(
       socket.getInputStream());
     dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(
       socket.getOutputStream());

     String messageFromClient = "";

     //If no message sent from client, this code will block the program
     messageFromClient = dataInputStream.readUTF();

     count++;
     message += "#" + count + " from " + socket.getInetAddress()
       + ":" + socket.getPort() + "\n"
       + "Msg from client: " + messageFromClient + "\n";

     MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
       msg.setText(message);
      }
     });

     String msgReply = "Hello from Android, you are #" + count;
     dataOutputStream.writeUTF(msgReply);

    }
   } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    final String errMsg = e.toString();
    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

     @Override
     public void run() {
      msg.setText(errMsg);
     }
    });

   } finally {
    if (socket != null) {
     try {
      socket.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }

    if (dataInputStream != null) {
     try {
      dataInputStream.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }

    if (dataOutputStream != null) {
     try {
      dataOutputStream.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }
   }
  }

 }

 private String getIpAddress() {
  String ip = "";
  try {
   Enumeration<NetworkInterface> enumNetworkInterfaces = NetworkInterface
     .getNetworkInterfaces();
   while (enumNetworkInterfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
    NetworkInterface networkInterface = enumNetworkInterfaces
      .nextElement();
    Enumeration<InetAddress> enumInetAddress = networkInterface
      .getInetAddresses();
    while (enumInetAddress.hasMoreElements()) {
     InetAddress inetAddress = enumInetAddress.nextElement();

     if (inetAddress.isSiteLocalAddress()) {
      ip += "SiteLocalAddress: "
        + inetAddress.getHostAddress() + "\n";
     }

    }

   }

  } catch (SocketException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
   ip += "Something Wrong! " + e.toString() + "\n";
  }

  return ip;
 }
}
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что адреса определяете верно и они пингуются между собой?

Comment: Да, я пробовал пинговать через командную строку. Пакеты проходят